# How do I find files by their extension in a specific directory and go through them with Power Shell?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to figure out how I would be able to do it. I have a directory which can be with multiple files, they named differently, but they all have the same extension (.ini). I need to somehow , search files by their extension and then in turn and order replace content's in each of them. Now I figured out how to get file by exact name (not by extension) and replace it's contents

```
@powershell -command "(Get-Content ..\Folder\File.ini).replace('TextToBeReplaced',\"NewText1`nNewText2") | Set-Content ..\Folder\File.ini"
```

What do I need to change?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
Get-ChildItem "c:\temp\" -recurse -file -filter "*.ini" | 
    %{$fullname=$_.fullname; (Get-Content $_.fullname).Replace("oldstring", "newstring") | Set-Content $fullname}
```

Comment: Vote++, but *please* don't use aliases in on-line examples.  For all learners out there: % = Foreach-Object

Comment: Thanks for the note :)

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way is using the `-Filter` parameter with `Get-ChildItem`:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.ext -Recurse
```